# about torsion and flat module

Tags: tensor-products, flatness

[image: d enter image description here]

Can someone explain me how (i) implies (ii) ?  What is that lopping off term does ?  And why at n=0 tensor is not exact?

Comment: Could you please give the reference of the quoted text?

Answer (score 0):

(i) $\implies$ (ii) by definition, since any flat $A$-module $M$ will have $\operatorname{Tor}_i (M, N) = 0$ for all $i > 0$ and all $N$.

The Tor functors are the derived functors of the tensor product. Starting with $0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$ as ses of modules and $N$ is any module (over a fixed commutative ring $R$), then $M' \otimes N \to M \otimes N \to M'' \otimes N \to 0$ is exact.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dots\longrightarrow P_2\otimes_A M\longrightarrow P_1\otimes_A M\longrightarrow P_0\otimes_A M\longrightarrow N\otimes_A M\longrightarrow 0$$
is an exact complex since $M$ is flat, so the lopped-off complex
$$\dots\longrightarrow P_2\otimes_A M\longrightarrow P_1\otimes_A M\longrightarrow P_0\otimes_A M\longrightarrow  0$$
is exact in *positive degree*. Therefore the homology of this complex is $0$ in positive degree, i.e. by definition of the Tor functors,
$$\operatorname{Tor}^A_n(M,N)=0\quad\forall n>0.$$

In degree $0$, we have the homology
\begin{align}
H_0&=\ker(P_0\otimes_A M\to 0)\big/\operatorname{Im}(P_1\otimes_A M\to P_0\otimes_A M)\\
&=P_0\otimes_A M\big/\operatorname{Im}(P_1\otimes_A M\to P_0\otimes_A M)\\
&\simeq N\otimes_A M.
\end{align}